# Actionascript Timer Errors

Tags: actionscript-3, timer, flash-cs6

Been working on a game called ChemoBlue for a while now and cannot seem to get rid of this error:

**EDIT: I changed a few lines of code and the error is now this:**

```
TypeError: Error #1009: Cannot access a property or method of a null object reference.
    at ChemoBlueSetup/levelUp()[/Users/raphaelhennessy/Desktop/STS/Gold Cinema ChemoBlue/ChemoBlueSetup.as:71]
```

I used to have a lot more errors thrown at me but now this is the only one. Heres the code that creates the error.
**EDIT: I did some debugging and it seems the error comes from here:**

```
public function levelUp(evt:MouseEvent):void
        {
            if (level == 1)
            {
                elementName.text = ("water");
                gotoAndPlay(1, "Level");
            }
                else if (level == 2)
            {
                elementName.text = ("sand");
                gotoAndPlay(1, "Level");
            }
            else if (level == 3)
            {
                elementName.text = ("???");
                gotoAndPlay(1, "Level");
            }
            }
```

Thanks in advance,
-Raph

Comment: There's not enough code provided for us to solve this problem.  According to the error, one of your variables was either not initialized or set to null.  The error occurred because that variable was accessed while it was still null.

Comment: I just edited my post as it turns out the error originates from the levelUp function instead of the gameWin function.

Answer (score 1):

Well I'm not sure if this will fix your problem, but your event listener currently has no parameters. All event listeners must have the event it listens for as a parameter.

So instead of

```
function frameUp2():void
```

it should say

```
function frameUp2(e:TimerEvent):void
```

Comment: The fact that you haven't gotten the error pointed out here means your code never even gets to this part. Are you sure your error originates here?

Comment: Have you imported Timer and TimerEvent?

Comment: He would get a different error otherwise. I think the problematic part is not the code above. Flash throws more informative errors if you check File > Publish Settings > Permit Debugging

Comment: I enabled Permit Debugging and it gave this error:          TypeError: Error #1009: Cannot access a property or method of a null object reference.
 at Function/ChemoBlueSetup/gameWin/frameUp2()[/Users/raphaelhennessy/Desktop/STS/Gold Cinema ChemoBlue/ChemoBlueSetup.as:636]
 at flash.utils::Timer/_timerDispatch()
 at flash.utils::Timer/tick()

Answer (score 0):

It seems I fixed it... in the function levelUp I removed the line making the dynamic text elementName say water if the level was one, which it wouldn't be anyway if that function was executed. Heres the code:

```
public function levelUp(evt:MouseEvent):void
        {
            if (level == 1)
            {
                gotoAndPlay(1, "Level");
            }
                else if (level == 2)
            {
                elementName.text = ("sand");
                gotoAndPlay(1, "Level");
            }
            else if (level == 3)
            {
                elementName.text = ("???");
                gotoAndPlay(1, "Level");
            }
        }
```

It throws no errors and acts just like I want it to. Thank you everybody!!
-Raph